# When deleting Facebook account, does the profile disappear immediately?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

If I delete my account, does my profile disappear immediately? I know it takes 14 days to delete my account, but can people still see my profile in between?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you [delete your account](https://www.facebook.com/help/224562897555674) it will disappear from everywhere immediately.

When you delete your account, people won't be able to see it on Facebook. It may take up to 90 days from the beginning of the deletion process to delete all of the things you've posted, like your photos, status updates or other data stored in backup systems. While Facebook deleting this information, it is inaccessible to other people using Facebook.